# Cannot send emails with shared mailbox if I simply type the FROM address

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, exchange

I'm having strange behaviour with one of my shared mailboxes (ie mailbox2)

Users with full access to this mailbox can reply as mailbox2, but they cannot send emails as mailbox2. I have tested with 2 users on seperate computers and both of them have the same problem.

I have an older mailbox1 shared mailbox that works perfectly... Now I've tried to create another shared mailbox called mailbox3 and is now having the same problem...

I have compared mailbox1 with mailbox2 in Powershell and they have exactly the same permissions. (FullAccess) ( both also have "send as" permissions in exchange online)

To clarify further... I CAN SEND EMAILS with the problematic mailbox HOWEVER I need to follow the following steps: "New email" => click "From" => I CANNOT select the problematic email adress here or CANNOT type the emailaddress here because mailing will fail, INSTEAD I MUST click "other email address" => click "from" again => search for the correct mailaddress in global address list => select the mailaddress => click OK => click OK

If I follow the steps above, I can send emails perfectly... BUT my users would like to select the email from the dropdown in the FROM box when writing a new email or simply type it in. Selecting or typing the email here always causes sending email to fail.

Any Idea what this could be?

I have tried to clear the cache of local outlook client, I have tried to manually add the shared mailbox, compared permissions with a working shared mailbox... No Luck...

I immediately get following reply when sending the mail:

__________________________________________--------------------------------------------
Van: Systeembeheerder
Verzonden: woensdag 26 april 2023 14:14
Onderwerp: Onbestelbaar: testt

Uw bericht heeft enkele of alle geadresseerden niet bereikt.

Onderwerp: testt
Verzonden: 26/04/2023 14:14

De volgende geadresseerde(n) zijn niet bereikt:

E op 26/04/2023 14:14
Dit bericht is niet verzonden. U bent niet gemachtigd om het bericht namens de opgegeven gebruiker te verzenden.

---

Diagnostische gegevens voor beheerders:

---

Fout is [0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524].

Exchange-antwoordheaders:
request-id: 99d633b6-cfc5-da09-e93e-bcf5ba0389ff
X-ServerApplication: Exchange/15.20.6340.019
X-FEServer: AM0PR05CA0082
X-BEServer: PAWPR10MB7367
X-CalculatedBETarget: PAWPR10MB7367.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-RequestId: {1E79AF9A-71ED-4B64-81A1-DEC86709DFFF}:107
X-ClientInfo: {50913F54-B756-48CF-B936-19FE401ABF76}:413520035
X-ElapsedTime: 93
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
X-ResponseCode: 0
X-DiagInfo: PAWPR10MB7367
X-RequestType: Execute

---

Overzicht van externe bewerkingen:

0: ropSetProps (10) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
Reactiecodes: 0
1: ropSetProps (10) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
Reactiecodes: 0
2: ropFlushRecipients (14) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
Reactiecodes: 0
3: ropSetProps (10) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
Reactiecodes: 0
4: ropTransportSend (74) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
Reactiecodes: 1244

---

Uitzonderingen bij reacties:

Index van externe bewerkingen: 4
Gekoppelde externe bewerkingen: ropTransportSend (74)
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.SendAsDeniedException: Can't send message. ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: Unable to send message. (hr=0x80070005, ec=1244)
0.35250:25020000, 1.36674:01000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:00000000, 1.36674:01000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:05000000, 1.44866:00000000, 1.36674:7A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:08000000, 1.44866:00140000, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:19000000, 1.44866:E00C0000, 1.36674:0E000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:FC0C0000, 1.44866:F5010000, 16.55847:BC0A0000, 17.43559:0000000034020000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FC498130000101F000130, 20.50032:140FC4988317F01FA4000000, 0.53414:12000000, 0.35180:14000000, 255.23226:15000000, 255.27962:7A000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:03000136, 0.35250:65020000, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:1A000000, 1.36674:4A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:1F000000, 1.44866:00000000, 16.55847:80000000, 17.43559:00000000A8030000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FC498130000000A000A80, 20.50032:140FC498831770200A007100, 0.53414:03000B67, 0.35180:83020000, 255.23226:0A00CE80, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:4A000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.44949:0A004366, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:1F000430, 0.38698:86000000, 1.41134:46000000, 0.37692:86000000, 0.37948:86000000, 5.33852:00000000534D545000010480, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B05000780, 7.57132:000000000000000005000780, 4.39640:DC040000, 1.63016:4A000000, 8.45434:7E20EB1B33BC6E4798ED714B403F2F4B00000000, 1.46798:13000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E363334302E3031393A504157505231304D42373336373A66653361616261382D653762332D343630372D616561392D6333386437366639326236343A3134383437363A2E4E455420362E302E313600000000, 7.51330:6B8CDFB34F46DB0886000000, 0.39570:86000000, 1.55954:0A000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:00000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:00000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.64146:4A000000, 1.33010:4A000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 1.33010:4A000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 255.1750:0A004E0E, 255.31418:0A003267, 0.22753:E2020000, 255.21817:DC040000, 0.34722:0A001870, 4.51106:DC040000, 0.41890:0A00773A, 4.58274:DC040000, 0.59285:EC020000, 4.46997:DC040000
at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.InternalThrowIfErrorOrWarning(String message, Int32 hresult, Boolean allowWarnings, Int32 ec, DiagnosticContext diagCtx, Exception innerException, MapiStore mapiStore)
at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, IExInterface iUnknown, Exception innerException, MapiStore mapiStore)
at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiBase.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hr)
at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiMessage.TransportSendMessage(PropValue[]& propsToReturn)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.StoreObjects.MapiAccessorExtensionMethods.TransportSendMessage(IStoreSession storeSession, Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropValue[]& mapiPropValues)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.StoreObjects.MapiAccessorExtensionMethods.TransportSendMessage(IStoreSession storeSession, Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropValue[]& mapiPropValues)
at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.CoreItem.TransportSend(PropertyDefinition[]& properties, Object[]& values)
at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.Message.TransportSend()
at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.RopHandler.<>c__DisplayClass156_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.ExceptionTranslator.TryExecuteCatchAndTranslateExceptions[TResult](Func`1 protectedCode, Func`2 errorCodeExtractor, Boolean noThrow, TResult& result, Exception& exception, ErrorCode& errorCode)

Transportverzending is mislukt: foutopsomming(25), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Transportverzending is mislukt: foutopsomming(22), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Berichtverzending is mislukt: bericht-id(2), foutopsomming(13), HResult(0x80070005), EC(1244).

Comment: Are you in a pure Exchange online environment? And all the aforementioned 3 shared mailboxes are created in Exchange Online, right?
How about sending as the shared mailbox(mailbox2 or mailbox3) from OWA by manually typing the email address?

Comment: It is possible that the first email was created as a licensed office 365 account and then later converted to a shared mailbox, but I'm not sure. 

If I type the address in OWA. The email seems to arrive... So it's probably a local outlook client problem?

Comment: PS. Yes it's a pure Exchange online environment. (regular office 365 for a small business)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across the official article below which indicates it could be an issue of outdated locally cached information used by OAB in Outlook:

[A user who has Send As permission can't send email messages as another user account in Outlook in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/a-user-who-has-send-as-permission-can-t-send-email-messages-as-another-user-account-in-outlook-in-office-365-920d8ff3-9978-fee5-ac4e-9cca042650ab)

Given this, use the resolution provided in the article or try one of the suggestions below:

1. Switch to Exchange Online mode via File > Account Settings > Account Settings, double click the account, unselect "Use Cached Exchange Mode...." and then restart Outlook.
2. Manually download OAB in Outlook via File > Account Settings > Download Address Book.

Comment: I think you are right that the problem may have been caused by outdated locally chached information. Unfortunately, the proposed solution in your link did not work. The problem however did resolve itself after a few days. 

Your suggestion may be a good solution but I'm unable to to test since the problem resolved itself.

Thank you for your kind and insightful responses.